# XQuery How can you add up values from similar XML structures with a unique identifier

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xquery

I have similiar XML structures eg.

```
<PLAYERS>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Jack</NAME>
        <SCORE>120</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Joe</NAME>
        <SCORE>100</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Jane</NAME>
        <SCORE>170</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
</PLAYERS>
```

and

```
<PLAYER>
    <NAME>Joe</NAME>
    <SCORE>40</SCORE>
</PLAYER>
<PLAYER>
    <NAME>Jane</NAME>
    <SCORE>20</SCORE>
</PLAYER>
```

I want to get the first data structure, but with the scores added up by the matching element `NAME`. For this example it would be:

```
<PLAYERS>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Jack</NAME>
        <SCORE>120</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Joe</NAME>
        <SCORE>140</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
    <PLAYER>
        <NAME>Jane</NAME>
        <SCORE>190</SCORE>
    </PLAYER>
</PLAYERS>
```

As you can see, each name which is not present in the second data set should still be showed in the final result. I came up with a few ideas, but the FLOWR expression used in XQuery is a bit confusing for me. Thought about using two for loops.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a grouping problem you can solve with `group by` clause https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-group-by:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'xml';
declare option output:indent 'yes';


declare variable $players2 as element(PLAYER)* := (<PLAYER>
    <NAME>Joe</NAME>
    <SCORE>40</SCORE>
</PLAYER>,
<PLAYER>
    <NAME>Jane</NAME>
    <SCORE>20</SCORE>
</PLAYER>);

<PLAYERS>
{
  for $players in (PLAYERS/PLAYER, $players2)
  group by $name := $players/NAME
  return 
    <PLAYER>
    {
        $players[1]/NAME,
       <SCORE>
           {
               sum($players/SCORE)

           }
       </SCORE>
       }
       </PLAYER>    
}
</PLAYERS>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV5

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I have a question. What exactly does `for $x in ($y, $z)`? Is this like two for loops?

Comment: The expression `(PLAYERS/PLAYER, $players2)` simply forms the sequence (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#construct_seq) of the `PLAYER` elements in `PLAYERS/PLAYER` and in the variable `$players2`. The `for $players in (PLAYERS/PLAYER, $players2)` expression clause (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-xquery-for-clause) then simply binds the variable `$players` to that sequence constructed with `(PLAYERS/PLAYER, $players2)` so that the rest of the FLWOR expression, in this case the subsequent `group by` clause, works on the sequence bound to `$players`.